# How do I set a value true on checked and false on unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a React app with a checkbox. I would like to include a checkbox that sends true when checked and false when unchecked. my onChange is:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

And the input is:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" value="true" id="My Value" 
     onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <span>My Value</span>
</label>
```

My State has:

```
   state = {
        My Value = ''
             }
```

When I submit with the checkbox checked, it works fine. The problem is when I check and uncheck, The value remains true instead of changing to false. How can I fix this. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update handler to consume checked value from event

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.id]: e.target.checked
  });
};
```

And don't hardcode checked value of input

```
<label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    className="filled-in"
    value={this.state['My Value']}
    id="My Value"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <span>My Value</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `value="true"` to `value={this.state["My Value"]}`